# dealing with a list of big .txt.gz files

Tags: python, r, file, bigdata

I'm new to dealing with big and compressed data so, I have some question regarding that

How can I read a list of **big (vep.txt.gz) files** in R or Python, then filter the content of the files based on two columns?

Should I decompress the files or just read them?

In python, I faced memory error because  the files is very big

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should decide for one language (remove the other tag) and describe what "filter the content" means (because the right answer depends on this).

Comment: I want to read multiple files then filter the content based on two columns (Two values) for example Virus: COVID & Type: Alpha, so I want to retrieve some of the rows then save them as a CSV file

Comment: This type of question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ @Maj

Comment: Iterate over the lines of each file in sequence; if a line meets your criteria write the info to a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

> then filter the content

You didn't describe much about the filtering operation.
I will assume you seek a `needle`.

Structure your python program so it accepts
some limited number of CSV lines on `sys.stdin`,
and use a `bash` pipeline like this:

```
$ zcat  < giant_haystack.csv.gz | grep NEEDLE | python my_prog.py
```

Or, move the filtering into your program, perhaps
with an `import re` regex that looks for NEEDLE
and discards non-matching lines.
Or teach your python app about decompressing gzip inputs.
Or consume filesystem space with `$ gunzip giant_haystack.csv.gz`
and have python read-and-retain a subset of those lines.

---

Suppose the regex `,Virus,.*,Type,` matches
the initial header line of your CSV.

You can use wildcards or brace expansion to name
a bunch of compressed input files:

```
HDR=",Virus,.*,Type,"
NEEDLE="COVID|Alpha"

for FILE in giant_haystack{1,2,3}.csv.gz
do
    zegrep "${HDR}|${NEEDLE}" < $FILE > small.csv
    python my_prog.py small.csv
done
```

Now your program is in a good position to
[read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
a smallish dataset and produce analytic results.
The input filename is available as `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: I want to read multiple files then filter the content based on two columns (Two values) for example Virus: COVID & Type: Alpha, so I want to retrieve some of the rows then save them as a CSV file

Comment: what did mean by (for FILE in giant_haystack{1,2,3}.csv.gz)?, the file's extension is .vep.txt.gz. @J_H